# How to put custom button & button link in sweet alert in Angular

Tags: angular, angular7, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Hay, can anyone tell me to how to put custom button to sweet alert2 and when click that new button how to redirect another page.

I want to add,
**Continue Button** and **Checkout Button**
when click Checkout Button, i want to redirect `[routerLink]="[ '/checkout ']"` page.

sweet alert 2
angular 7 cli

`Swal.fire("Done", "Succefull added to shopping cart !", "success");`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this html. And in ts add a navigate function and route to any page.

```
swal.fire({
   html: '<button (click)="navigate()">Goto</button>
})
```

Comment: Hay, i try to put navigate function, but it did not work.

`Swal.fire({
        html: '<button (click)="goToCheckOut()">Goto</button> ' })`

**Function** `goToCheckOut() {
  this._router.navigate(['/address']);
}`

Comment: try with a console.log inside your gotocheckout function. If it works then there is issue with routing.